# How to calculate the price of an asset using Black-Scholes equation?

Tags: black-scholes

I'm trying to solve this problem given:

> The dividend yield for asset 1 (asset 2) is 0.05 (0.03), and it is
>   also given the time zero stock prices, and both assets' Black-Scholes
>   equation.

I need to find the time zero price of an asset which pays:

$[max(S_{3}^{1}-S_{3}^{2},0)]$ at T = 3.

Just wanted to get a hint on how to approach the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you are after is an exchange option on the two assets, i.e., a zero-strike call option on the price difference between `asset1` and `asset2`. Having the equations of motion for both asset prices, you are in a position to work out:

i) the forward prices for both assets at $T=3$;

ii) both assets' volatilities $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$; AND

iii) the correlation coefficient $\rho_{1,2}$.

Having all of this, you can apply the Margrabe formula [Margrabe's formula on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margrabe%27s_formula)